# Sql Splitting Function

Tags: sql, string, function, split

I have a string like that  "10*cat*123456;12*rat*789;15*horse*365"  i want to split it to be like that "cat, rat, horse"   I have made this     Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@BenNames VARCHAR(2000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tmp VARCHAR(2000)
    SET @tmp = @BenNames    
    SET @tmp = SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING(@tmp, CHARINDEX('*', @tmp) + 1, LEN(@tmp)),
            0,
            CHARINDEX('*', SUBSTRING(@tmp, CHARINDEX('*', @tmp) + 1, LEN(@tmp)))
        )
    RETURN @tmp    but it only split only one part "10*cat*123456"
```

i want to send every part to this by another function or another looop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itai/archive/2009/02/01/t-sql-split-function.aspx

Comment: sorry all, I didn't give myself time to understand the idea  thank you "pb"